# Error while getting client credentials token: invalid_client on interactive login with Sitecore CLI

Tags: login, sitecore-cli

I am using the Sitecore CLI to login (interactive) to my local instance and that works fine.

We have a setup for a non-interactive login for the CLI to the cloud dev environment. I wanted to test that locally and it succeeds. I can login and perform tasks.

When I now want to login to my local instance again however I get an error:

```
Error while getting client credentials token: invalid_client
```

I am using the commands from the official docs here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/log-in-to-a-sitecore-instance-with-sitecore-command-line-interface.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue can be fixed by setting the `--client-credentials` argument to false in the interactive login command:

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority https://<Sitecore identity server> --cm http://<Sitecore instance> --allow-write true --client-credentials false
```

When using the non-interactive login this is set to true. And apparently if you do a new login that argument is not reset to the default (false) so you need to apply it.

A simple fix for something that might be trivial for some but maybe I can save someone time by sharing here.

Answer (score -1):

Try bypass command:

```
.\up.ps1 -bypass $true
```

Comment: Please add more details with your answer.

Comment: Explain why your command would help OP with his issue